# terminating index process for search engine

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

i am working on a small search-engine app with asp.net 4.0. the indexing process can index each URL founded in each document and this recursively performed for each other. now how i can terminate this process when i want or when user clicked on stop browser button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the browser stop button is a good solution to your problem. If I understand correctly you have a recursive url indexing algorithm that does not have a base case.  Meaning the algorithm does not know when to stop.  I have a couple suggestions that might help you out.

1) Instead of using the stop button in the browser put an actual button on the page.  Think of having a "start" and "stop" button.

or

2) Implement a base case for your recursive algorithm so that it knows when to stop automatically.  The base case could be the algorithm could stop after going a predefined or user defined number of levels deep into the url structure.